# Drawing box arround text in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, style

I need text labels with surrounding a box and a specific fill color. Actually I have the following function which only shows the text but I don't know how to draw a box around the text. Text length is always different, so it must consider the text length. Can anybody show me how to implement it?

```
function showLabel(mapPos) {
  var textStop = replaceAll(mapPos['text'],"|","");
  //textStop = replaceAll(textStop," ","&nbsp;");
  //textStop = replaceAll(textStop,"-","&ndash;");
  var lblFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([mapPos['lng'],mapPos['lat']],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'))
  });
  var textPos = new ol.style.Text({
    textAlign: 'left',
    textBaseline: 'middle',
    //font: 'bold 16px arial',
    font: '16px arial',
    text: textStop,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#000000'}),
    //stroke has bad performance
    //stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: mapPos['color'], width: 1}),
    offsetX: 16,
    offsetY: -16,
    rotation: 0
  });
  //TODO: Draw a box arround the text
  var lblStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: textPos
  });
  lblFeature.setStyle(lblStyle);
  return lblFeature;
} //End showLabel()
```

So far I do not get any error in the console.log. I guess it must be done near my TODO Label. `mapPos` is an array where in `mapPos['text']` is text available.

In version 2 I was able to do it like this function:

```
var markerFlag = new Array();
function showPosition(mapPos) {
  var size = new OpenLayers.Size(24,24);
  var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('../images/map24/'+mapPos['symbolid']+'.gif',size);
  var myLonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(mapPos['lng'],mapPos['lat']).transform(
    proj4326, //Transform from WGS 1984
    projmerc //To Spherical Mercator Projection
  );
  var textPos = replaceAll(mapPos['text'],"|","");
  textPos = replaceAll(textPos," ","&nbsp;");
  textPos = replaceAll(textPos,"-","&ndash;");
  var myOptionsText = {
    mouseOver: false,
    labelOffsetTop: '-58px',
    labelOffsetLeft: '22px',
    backGroundColor: mapPos['color']
  };
  layer_position.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(myLonLat,icon.clone(),myOptionsText));
  if (mapPos['text']) {
    layer_banner.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker.Label(myLonLat,icon.clone(),textPos,myOptionsText));
  }
} //End showPosition()
```

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to achieve the desired effect using the `ol.Overlay` class of OpenLayers:

Here is a small snippet:

```
// a coordinate in the view projection
var pos = ol.proj.fromLonLat([16.3725, 48.208889]);

// Vienna label
var vienna = new ol.Overlay({
  position: pos,
  element: document.getElementById('vienna')
});
map.addOverlay(vienna);
```

In your HTML you'll need a matching element:

```
<a class="overlay" id="vienna" target="_blank" 
  href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna">Vienna</a>
```

And in the CSS the following styles:

```
#vienna {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

This looks as follows

[image: The rendered ol.Overlay]

Here is the [running jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1uguu4h/2/), which is just the original 
overlay example with a bit of CSS added.

Comment: NB this would not be rendered on the canvas

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get this done by using a SVG shape behind the Text element and fill-up the shape with color, to achieve the same result.

I had to resize the background shape to match the size of text element and it wasn't as straightforward as I was hoping for.

The main blocks were:

- SVG items don't have background style, and `fill` attribute on `text` element would only change the text color not its background color. That's why I had to use another shape in the first place.
- When a SVG element is used as the source of an image element, all the javascript code inside it is ignored for security reasons. Therefore, you can't dynamically check/change sizes.
- Shapes and Paths inside the SVG element are not part of DOM, so you can't access or style them with JavaScript or CSS.

First thing I did was to use the following code -- that I found somewhere on Stackoverflow, to get the width of the rendered text in pixels:

```
/* Get the rendered size of a text, in pixels */
/* _text: "Blah blah" */
/* _fontStyle: "Normal 12px Arial" */
function getTextWidth ( _text, _fontStyle ) {

    var canvas = undefined,
        context = undefined,
        metrics = undefined;

    canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" )

    context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

    context.font = _fontStyle;
    metrics = context.measureText( _text );

    return metrics.width;
}
```

Then I used it inside my other function which was generating the marker and its label:

```
...
labelFontStyle = "Normal 12px Arial";

labelWidth = getTextWidth( _text, labelFontStyle );
labelWidth = labelWidth + 10;

iconSVG = '<svg ' +
            'version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ' +
            'x="0px" y="0px" width="' + labelWidth + 'px" height="16px" ' +
            'viewBox="0 0 ' + labelWidth + ' 16" enable-background="new 0 0 ' + labelWidth + ' 16" xml:space="preserve">'+
                '<rect x="0" y="0" width="' + labelWidth + '" height="16" stroke="#000000" fill="#DEEFAE" stroke-width="2"></rect>' +
                '<text x="5" y="13" fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" font-weight="normal">' + _text + '</text>' +
        '</svg>';

imageElement = new Image();
imageElement.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape( iconSVG );

iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    "image": new ol.style.Icon({
        "img": imageElement,
        "imgSize":[labelWidth, 66],
        "anchor": [0.5, 0.5],
        "offset": [0, -50]
    })
});

feature = new ol.Feature({
    "geometry": new ol.geom.Point(
        ol.proj.fromLonLat( [_longitude, _latitude] )
    )
});

feature.setStyle( iconStyle );

return feature;
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 4.6.0, there are now BackgroundFill, BackgroundStroke and Padding properties for ol.style.Text.
You can set them to draw rectangles behind your labels :

```
backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'})
```

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html#setBackgroundFill

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I needed. 
Your link was dead so I edited it to this current one: 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html#setBackgroundFill

Comment: Anyone has a problem with this? where the background fills a whole screen in height

Comment: @Rivenfall Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TimAutin It's been a while I don't remember this specific issue

Comment: Someone having problems with background fill and safari browser. In my case the text overlaps box in safari. Chrome works fine

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not know how to add a rectangle to a label in OL, but if it's just for readability purposes maybe a stroke around the labels like shown in this [OpenLayers Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html) could fit your needs.

Comment: Yes I've seen this example, but it would not help. A stroke will also not help because using a lot of labels like I do it gives a very bad performance. so this is not the case.